# What is the correct syntax if I want to add more than one condition in a "ng-disable"?

Tags: angularjs, html

Currently this is my ng-disable condition:

```
ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid "
```

Basically if one or more inputs are empty, my button "submit" is disabled. Now I have an ID which needs to be validated first and if it is invalid, my button "submit" remains disabled. Im new to html5 btw.

Is there like a true and true = true?

This is my ID:

```
<input type="text" ng-blur ="register.validateid();" name="referalid" placeholder="Referal ID" ng-model="register.data.referalid"  required="required" style="background-color:transparent; min-width:230px;"/>
            <div class="helpers" ng-if="registerForm.referalid.$touched">
            <span ng-if="registerForm.referalid.$error.required"  class="help-block" style="color:red;">This field requires a VALID Referal ID!</span>
            </div>
            </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write conditions inline or create a function in a controller which checks all the validation conditions and returns true/false.

The code will look like:

```
ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid && condition2"
```

Or

```
ng-disabled="validateForm()"
```

Comment: The rest of my form just checks the input, but my ID checks if the ID is valid, Ive done the ID checking, but even when my ID is wrong, my "submit" button becomes enable. Can you teach me a correct syntax to say; that registerForm.$invalid && (if ID is invalid)

Comment: if you have a complex logic for validation, choose method syntax. Write your validation code in a function. After calculation, if your form is valid, return true, else return false.

For example,
function validateForm(){
   if(validateId($scope.Id) && registerForm.$invalid) return true;
   else return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

Just as with any other expression you can use multiple conditions separated with normal javascript operators like `&&` or `||`:

```
ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid && someOtherCondition"
```

You can also provide function, it's still valid expression:

```
ng-disabled="isDisabled(registerForm)"
```

Comment: how do I address my ID field? by name or by id? Thanks for the help

Comment: is it like this: ng-disabled="registerForm.$invalid && referalid.$invalid "

Comment: Yes, you address fields by name.